# Iptable & routing in a virtualbox lab

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, iptables

I set up a virtual box lab, with the following configuration:

[image: Vitual Lab Setup]

In  order to make the lab working I create with a script the following interfaces, enabling port forwarding for the server machine in order to have internet access.

This commands are triggered from **HOST** machine

```
tunctl -t tap0 -u myuser
ip link set up dev tap0
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tap0
ip link set up dev br0
ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev br0
ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 dev br0
tunctl -t tap1 -u myuser
tunctl -t tap2 -u myuser
tunctl -t tap3 -u myuser
ip link set up dev tap1
ip link set up dev tap2
ip link set up dev tap3
brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br1 tap1
brctl addif br1 tap2
brctl addif br1 tap3
ip link set up dev br1
ip addr add 10.1.2.1/24 dev br1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Using virtualbox gui I set the following interfaces to serve and clients:

server  -> tap0 , tap1 [Bridged network]

client1 -> tap2 [Bridged network]

client2 -> tap3 [Bridged network]

Then edit **/etc/network/interfaces** and **resolv.conf**

**SERVER**

```
*# cat /etc/network/interfaces*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add default gw 10.1.1.1 dev eth0
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.1.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0

*# cat /etc/resolv.conf*
domain 
search 
nameserver 192.168.2.194
```

**CLIENT 1**

```
*# cat /etc/network/interfaces*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.2.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add default gw 10.1.2.2 dev eth0

*# cat /etc/resolv.conf*
domain 
search 
nameserver 10.1.2.2
```

**CLIENT 2**

```
*# cat /etc/network/interfaces*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.2.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add default gw 10.1.2.2 dev eth0

*# cat /etc/resolv.conf*
domain 
search 
nameserver 10.1.2.2
```

With the following configuration:

I can access the internet with server machine,

I can access via ssh to any machine in the network

**I can't access internet with client1 and client2 machine...**

Can you help me setting up some routing rule to get rid of this problem?

Comment: i forgot to mention the fact that host, server, client1 and client2 are all debian

Comment: From any of the clients, can you `ping -c1 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: And,  on which machine are you running the first set of instructions, the one that begins with `tunctl`? On the host?

Comment: no, i can't ping google DNS, from client machines i can only reach 10.1.2.x addresses

Comment: yes of course, i omitted to say cause i thought it was obvious....

Answer (score 0):

> And, on which machine are you running the first set of instructions, the one that begins with `tunctl`? On the host?
>
> yes of course, i omitted to say cause i thought it was obvious....

Not necessarily: the **all-important** iptables rule

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

which **should** have been on the server, is instead to be found on the (useless!) host. Ditto for

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Lastly, (but independent of the above), the statement

```
nameserver 10.1.2.2
```

on both clients is a tad suspicious: did you setup a DNS server on the Server? Until you do, you are better off using

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

or something of this sort.

I cannot state that these are the **only** errors in your configuration. There is so much that is useless (a bridge made only of a virtual interface??? A bridge on the Host? VBox will take care of that! a statement like

```
nameserver 192.168.2,194
```

with a comma instead of a dot), that I can only state that the points I made above ought to be corrected, but then most likely an extra round of debugging will be needed. When you do that, make sure to use `tcpdump` to check where the packet flow is broken, because that makes network debugging so much easier than *I can go from here to there, but not from ...*.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, the comma is a typo, in my conf is a dot.

Comment: i made this conf because i want client machine access internet via sever machine, not directly.

Comment: nella creazione del lab sono sicuro della bontà delle scelte operate in virtu delle esigenze che ho, il mio problema è creare sul server una regola che mi pemetta di accedere ad internet da un client seguendo lo stesso "giro" con cui il server va verso l'esterno...spero di essere stato un po piu chiaro cosi...

Comment: English guys. Super user wants to help everyone who sees this question.